# Plugin hook "after_platform_add" not launched when running `ionic state restore` after git clone

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am trying to document a repeatable process for developers here to get clean copies of an ionic project from GitHub and then populate the plugins and platforms folders of the project. My `package.json` has the `cordovaPlugins` and `cordovaPlatforms` listed.  Here are the steps I am trying:

```
$ git clone <repo-url>
$ cd <project-dir>
$ npm install
$ bower install
$ ionic state restore
```

This almost does what I expect, but not quite.  I get the `plugins` folder populated with all of the plugin source files.  I also get the `platforms/ios` folder populated with the project for iOS.  The problem is, none of the `after_platform_add` scripts in the plugins are run.

It seems like the order of operations when running the `ionic state restore` command might be the issue.  It adds the platforms listed in the package.json before fetching the plugins.

The only work-around I have been able to come up with is to ask each developer to run `ionic platform remove ios` followed by `ionic platform add ios`.  The down-side of having them do this is it causes the `package.json` file to be touched.  This then results in developers needlessly committing changes in `package.json` to git.

Is there a way to cause the after_platform_add hook to run?

Comment: why do you want hooks to run? if `ionic state restore` is installing all plugins and restoring platform for you. If you read ionic cli documentation this is what they say `Ionic now provides a command to help you manage the state of your Ionic application. Previously Cordova hooks were used to save platforms and plugins to your package.json file.` , so hooks are not supposed to run with this command.

Comment: There are platform specific changes that some hooks require to be made in the native build environments **after** ionic creates the platform project file. For example, some plugins require additional compiler switches or linker directives. The only way I am aware of to do this is with a script in the after_platform_add hook. These scripts are distributed with the plugin and are set to run only when the specific platform is added. To me it seems like this sort of platform specific configuration is part of the state, and it should be restored during the ionic state restore process.

Comment: Another need for after_platform_add is to copy config files into the respective pltform folders, like api keys that plugins need, etc. Since platform restore doesn't fire the after_platform_add hook, there's not a way to do this cleanly

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution to this issue. In package.json, add this:

```
"scripts": {
"postinstall": "bower install && gulp && ionic platform add android && ionic platform add ios && ionic state restore",
"clean": "ionic platform remove android && ionic platform remove ios && git checkout package.json"
```

},

This will accomplish what you need, and also reverts any changes to package.json by running git checkout on it. To run this, do:

```
npm run-script clean && npm install
```